# Preserving line breaks in xml node

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, domdocument

I'm trying to convert lines in an XML node into an unordered list, however I'm having some difficulty.

Take for example this node :

```
 <test>
      Line1
      Line2
      Line3
 </test>
```

I would like to transform it into this with PHP

```
 <ul>
      <li>Line1</li>
      <li>Line2</li>
      <li>Line3</li>
 </ul>
```

I've tried using DOMDocument and SimpleXML, however neither seem to retain the newlines. When echoed, the node value looks like this :

```
 Line1 Line2 Line3
```

I've also tried `explode` in order to have an array containing each line as an element :

```
 $lines = explode( '\n', $node->nodeValue);
```

However, it only returns an array with one element, so I can't make an unordered list with it.

Is there a simple way for me to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to kick yourself. `'\n'` should be `"\n"`! Here's a full example:

```
$Dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$Dom->loadXML(
'<test>
    Line1
    Line2
    Line3
</test>');

$value = $Dom->documentElement->nodeValue;
$lines = explode("\n", $value);
$lines = array_map('trim', $lines); // remove leading and trailing whitespace
$lines = array_filter($lines); // remove empty elements

echo '<ul>';
foreach($lines as $line) {
    echo '<li>', htmlentities($line), '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: ...You're right, it works, thank you. Such a small oversight caused me so much trouble, I'll begin kicking myself now.